# Getting duration as null while using google map direction matrix api

Tags: java, android, api

I am trying to develop a bus tracker app.The app basically collects location data from firebase and gets the user current location and gives estimated time duration to travel using googleMap distance matrix api.The app is accessing the 2 locations properly, but giving null value for duration. Here is my code to print the duration. I have DistanceMatrixResponse,Distance,Duration,DistanceMatrixElement,DistanceMatrixRow,Location1,Location2 ,RetrofitService classes and  GMapAPIService Interface.The code works fine when the parameters for getCompleteAddress is directly in the form of double(for ex:final String ORIGINS = getCompleteAddress(12.841,80.157)) .but when fetched using the getter function ,the code stops after 5th loop(like it prints till T5)but won't go to next if condition. I am getting proper location values when i am printing it using Log inside onResponse and I can see value of both locations are not same. I am trying to figure it out for days now but not getting anywhere.

```
    private void getTravelTime() {

        final String API_KEY = "MyAPIKey";
        final String ORIGINS = getCompleteAddress(l.getLatitue(),l.getLongitude());
       final String DESTINATIONS = getCompleteAddress(l1.getLatitue(), l1.getLongitude());
       

        GMapAPIService gMapAPIService = RetrofitService.getRetrofitClient().create(GMapAPIService.class);

        Call<DistanceMatrixResponse> call = gMapAPIService.getDistance(API_KEY, ORIGINS, DESTINATIONS);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<DistanceMatrixResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<DistanceMatrixResponse> call, Response<DistanceMatrixResponse> response) {

                Log.d("l", String.valueOf(l.getLatitue()+ " "+l.getLongitude()));
                Log.d("l1", String.valueOf(l1.getLatitue()+ " "+l1.getLongitude()));
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    DistanceMatrixResponse distanceMatrixResponse = response.body();
                    Log.d("T1","Here");

                    if (distanceMatrixResponse != null) {

                        List<DistanceMatrixRow> rows = distanceMatrixResponse.getRows();
                        Log.d("T2","Here");
                        if (rows != null && !rows.isEmpty()) {
                            Log.d("T3","Here");
                            DistanceMatrixRow distanceMatrixRow = rows.get(0);
                            Log.d("D2",String.valueOf(distanceMatrixRow));

                            if (distanceMatrixRow != null) {
                                Log.d("T4","Here");
                                DistanceMatrixElement distanceMatrixElement = distanceMatrixRow.getElements().get(0);
                                Log.d("D2",String.valueOf(distanceMatrixElement));

                                if (distanceMatrixElement != null) {
                                    Log.d("T5","Here");
                                    Duration duration = distanceMatrixElement.getDuration();
                                    Distance d=distanceMatrixElement.getDistance();
                                    Log.d("Duration:",String.valueOf(duration));
                                    Log.d("Distance:",String.valueOf(d));


                                    if (duration != null) {
                                        Log.d("T6","Here");
                                        String travelTime = duration.getText();
                                        textViewTravelTime.setText(travelTime);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }



            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<DistanceMatrixResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                Log.e("MainActivity", t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
```

[This is the output I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACnpK.jpg)